# Regular expression, not outputting values correctly

Tags: regex, list, python-3.x

```
num = re.findall (r'[-+]?\d*\.*\d+' , str (table))
```

Hi all I have this regular expression and it is printing the values i want. However, they are separated.

For example:

```
['7', '336.82', '-3.89', '-0.05', '7', '351.60', '7', '322.86', '7', '340.71']
```

is what it prints

But i want it to print:

```
['7,336.82', '-3.89', '-0.05', '7,351.60', '7,322.86', '7,340.71']
```

Please could someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want to capture numbers that are separated by comma. You can use:

```
r'[-+]?(?:\d+[\d,]*)?\.?\d+'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JpiHYi/1)

Answer (score 0):

If validating numbers by mandatory 3 digits after comma is necessary:

```
[-+]?\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?
```

if input is `1,000,00.0` it means: `1,000` and `00.0` in this answer.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8nYbaQ/2

If `01,123` should be reject: (because of starting 0 digit)

```
(\+?[1-9]|\-\d)\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8nYbaQ/3

Comment: Hi, great answer... Thanks so much.